# How to insert row into a SQL table with auto-increment primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which holds only one column - an auto-incrementing primary key.

I need to insert values to this table in order to generate new ID.

Here is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [InvestmentJourneys]
(
    [InvestmentJourneyId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
        CONSTRAINT [PK_InvestmentJourneys] 
            PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([InvestmentJourneyId])
)
```

I've tried this:

```
INSERT INTO [InvestmentJourneys] ([InvestmentJourneyId]) 
VALUES (NULL)
```

But I get an error since this column is the primary key.

I would appreciate any suggestion here on how to achieve this.

Comment: Since this table has only a single column which is an incrementing number have you considered using a sequence instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like so:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.InvestmentJourneys
DEFAULT VALUES;
```

Comment: Didn't know that syntax. Works in PostgreSQL as well. And the nerd in me found out that in MySQL it works as `insert into t () values ();`.

Comment: Ah, now as a challenge let's see if you know how to generate multiple of these in one statement. Took me a while to figure it out, let's just say you can't do it on version 2005 or earlier.

Comment: Not sure you can't with the above, @Charlieface . If you were in an IDE such as SSMS, you could use `GO {n}`, but that's technically not a single statement but the same one being executed *n* times. Though, if you have a table with a single `IDENTITY` column and you want to generate multiple rows I would suggest that you have a flawed design.

Comment: Thought I'd get you on that one :-) The trick is `MERGE` with the source a tally table of the amount of rows needed, and `ON 1 = 0 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT DEFAULT VALUES`, I combined that with an `OUTPUT` clause to get the actual values back to the client. Pretty horrible. Admittedly, I once had to deal with part of our database that was built before `SEQUENCE` was around, yeah pretty bad design.